# How to sort a TypeScript map from the current weekday?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a map containing the sales for the last week. It is like this

```
Friday 0
Monday 0
Saturday 0
Sunday 0
Thursday 0
Tuesday 0
Wednesday 0
```

I want to sort it so from the current day it sorts the map backwards from the current day. So if the day is **Thursday** I want it to sort like this

```
Thursday 0
Friday 0
Saturday 0
Sunday 0
Monday 0
Tuesday 0
Wednesday 0
```

The key is a string and the value is a number in TypeScript. It also could be converted into an array of objects with the weekday and value.

Comment: How have you tried to solve this?

Comment: If [this](https://tsplay.dev/mb1Y4N) answers your question, I can write it up in an answer with an explanation. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn it sent me on the right path. Yes you can type it as an answer I will accept. Thank you. I am impressed with your TypeScript.

Comment: Not a downvoter but you should explain what you have tried and what didn't work. This site is about precise answers to precise questions. Your question has several possible solutions.

Comment: What I tried wasnt worth showing, wrong approach.

Comment: I don't think anything is not worth showing, it shows your thought path, your effort and it could narrow your broad problem down to a simpler one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mutable array of weekday names as a reference for the *relative* order:

```ts
type Weekday =
  | "Monday"
  | "Tuesday"
  | "Wednesday"
  | "Thursday"
  | "Friday"
  | "Saturday"
  | "Sunday";

const weekdays: Weekday[] = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday",
];
```

Then you can use it to perform the sort operation on the map in another function.

Because [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instances can't actually be sorted (they "remember the original insertion order of the keys" [<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#:%7E:text=remembers%20the%20original%20insertion%20order%20of%20the%20keys)) the sort operation involves copying the entries out of the map, clearing the map, then copying them back in — in the desired sort order.

In the function below, the index of the target weekday name is found in the array, then that element and all following elements are shifted to the beginning of the array so that it has the weekdays in the desired order. Then they're iterated over to sort the map in the same order:

```ts
function sortMap(map: Map<Weekday, number>, first: Weekday): void {
  const index = weekdays.indexOf(first);
  weekdays.unshift(...weekdays.splice(index, weekdays.length - index));
  const cache = new Map(map.entries());
  map.clear();
  for (const weekday of weekdays) {
    if (cache.has(weekday)) map.set(weekday, cache.get(weekday)!);
  }
}
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA6hEGsAmBDEUC8AoAkAHygCIBZAewDtURDcDCAVAVwgGcqb8i4lzX3ai9ABaMATmzQc6AMVEBLfp0IBlFMDGK6yxpUkBuLFgDGFFsCgB3eMjQsAXLGtUA2gF1MUZ7hIV2AGm8mPkkAnEJuXglqUIYRcX9vWQUQ71V1UQSw7V1orFcDLAAzHSNgOQooFlJRYGIUMAAKAFt6hzqwAB44RCo-KHJGJoAjCFEAPj7CuXFgB26bEABKBwA3UgUoAG9cE3IzKDlKCAAPDyse2wA6Q6QTgHlChqmZxYMcc4WWS50WITlC4ANS7Aj5UL4sMAAGzkRggDRuJz6oKukIg5AA5sAhFAALQHI7HRavHamcxGFBGITQDD9CAWKDtZr1S5o4DyVgNIlvFpgS5GVEoUSct6FapQBq7fbI9CkQqWJy2RZbXA4f7i8mUiCXIQoFgNaVEqA8y4sCCA6V9DVUy7os36hVLACExJwAF8sO7jKSjfUPLx6e0ug6+gNhqMxg0vDhnIQkv4oAAGVyhGNkHKEPpJlMqNQaEKJ5O4GPZeNZouxMRRDMF7NBKuZwvR8IQHjBaI1vLErBVGqMnl9CvxSTEyWkVGXSGkdENQdROzV5zAy7G1nsvWLVzEnu1epMsADtPsEemMdayfTnw5ed9RfAlfkNlyDkb4kAelfUEAZARmoyXLBAA)

Here's the compiled JavaScript from the TS Playground in a runnable snippet so you can verify that it works according to the expectations in your question:

```js
const weekdays = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday",
];

function sortMap(map, first) {
  const index = weekdays.indexOf(first);
  weekdays.unshift(...weekdays.splice(index, weekdays.length - index));
  const cache = new Map(map.entries());
  map.clear();
  for (const weekday of weekdays) {
    if (cache.has(weekday)) map.set(weekday, cache.get(weekday));
  }
}

const map = new Map([
  ["Friday", 0],
  ["Monday", 0],
  ["Saturday", 0],
  ["Sunday", 0],
  ["Thursday", 0],
  ["Tuesday", 0],
  ["Wednesday", 0],
]);

sortMap(map, "Thursday");
console.log("Thursday:", [...map.entries()]);
sortMap(map, "Monday");
console.log("Monday:", [...map.entries()]);
// …etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work, I used day js to get the current day.  This answer is written in TypeScript.

```
    import dayjs from 'dayjs';

type DayData = {
    [key: string]: number;
};

function sortDays(data: DayData): DayData {
    const daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    
    // Get the current day using dayjs
    const currentDay = daysOfWeek[dayjs().day()];

    // Reorder the days starting from the current day
    const startIndex = daysOfWeek.indexOf(currentDay);
    const orderedDays = [
        ...daysOfWeek.slice(startIndex),
        ...daysOfWeek.slice(0, startIndex),
    ];

    // Create a new sorted data map
    const sortedData: DayData = {};
    orderedDays.forEach(day => {
        sortedData[day] = data[day];
    });

    return sortedData;
}

// Example usage
const data: DayData = {
    "Friday": 0,
    "Monday": 0,
    "Saturday": 0,
    "Sunday": 0,
    "Thursday": 0,
    "Tuesday": 0,
    "Wednesday": 0
};

const sortedData = sortDays(data);
console.log(sortedData);
```

please up vote me

Comment: HI. Thanks for the reply. I am waiting for @jsejcksn to reply as I used his code. BUt I have upped your answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```js
const currentDay = new Date().getDay();

enum Days {
  Monday = 1,
  Tuesday = 2,
  Wednesday = 3,
  Thursday = 4,
  Friday = 5,
  Saturday = 6,
  Sunday =7,
}

const map:Record<keyof typeof Days, number> = {
  Monday: 0,
  Tuesday: 0,
  Wednesday: 0,
  Thursday: 0,
  Friday: 0,
  Saturday: 0,
  Sunday: 0,
}

console.log(Object.entries(map).sort(([aDay, aValue], [bDay, bValue]) => {
  const aDayValue = Days[aDay as keyof typeof Days];
  const aDistanceFromToday = currentDay - aDayValue;
  const aFinalDistance = aDistanceFromToday < 0 ? aDistanceFromToday + 7 : aDistanceFromToday;

  const bDayValue = Days[bDay as keyof typeof Days];
  const bDistanceFromToday = currentDay - bDayValue;
  const bFinalDistance = bDistanceFromToday < 0 ? bDistanceFromToday + 7 : bDistanceFromToday;

  return bFinalDistance - aFinalDistance;
}))
```